# Expression tree evaluation without recursion in c

Tags: c, loops, tree, expression

I want to write a function where an expression tree is passed and the result of the arithmetic expression tree is returned. I saw a lot of question and read a lot of blogs. All of them says to use stack and blindly print it in inorder. But since I have operators too in the tree, simply printing them wont help. How can I evaluate the arithmetic expression? Thank you.

the expression tree structure

```
typedef struct EXPR_NODE{

    char *type;
    char *content;

    struct EXPR_NODE *left_node;
    struct EXPR_NODE *right_node;
  
    struct EXPR_NODE *prev_node;  //this is for stack operation only
    struct EXPR_NODE *next_node;  //this is for stack operation only

} expr_node;
```

so my sample expression will be 2 * 1 + 3

```
expr_node *root = calloc(1, sizeof(expr_node));
root->type = "+";
root->content = "PLUS";

expr_node *left1 = calloc(1, sizeof(expr_node));
left1->type = "3";
left1->content = "INT";

expr_node *right1 = calloc(1, sizeof(expr_node));
right1->type = "*";
right1->content = "ASTERIX";

//left and right of root

root->left_node = left1;
root->right_node = right1


expr_node *left2 = calloc(1, sizeof(expr_node));
left2->type = "1";
left2->content = "INT";

expr_node *right2 = calloc(1, sizeof(expr_node));
right2->type = "2";
right2->content = "INT";

//left and right of right1
right1->left_node = left2;
right1->left_node = right2;
```

so the tree looks like

```
       +
      / \
     3   *
        / \
       1   2
```

So when I pass the root node to the function I need it return 5 in String. I accomplished it with recursion but i need to do it with iteration.

Comment: `root->right_node = right1` You are adding the node **before** it's created!

Comment: @4386427 yup changed.

Comment: Convert the tree to reverse polish and then evaluate from there.

Comment: @cup thats how i constructed the tree in the first place.

Comment: ohhhhh @cup yess, i think i asnwered my own question thanks mate.

Comment: Question should be closed then...

Comment: Yes close the question then @trincot